How can I use JavaScript to convert a byte array (ArrayBuffer) into a live stream video?
I have created a screen recording application in Java, which works fine and encodes the video stream using MediaCodec. Then, I send the bytes through a socket connection to JavaScript. However, I am having trouble playing the live stream after converting the bytes to a stream using JavaScript libraries such as Bradway.js and Jmuxer.js.
Here is some code that has been tested:
/Bradway.js/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Live Video Stream</title>
    <style>
  
        #videoCanvas {
            display: block;
            width: 640px; /* Adjust as needed */
            height: 480px; /* Adjust as needed */
            border: 1px solid black; /* Optional border for visualization */
        }
    </style>
    <script src="./Decoder.js"></script>
    <script src="./Player.js"></script>
    <script src="./YUVCanvas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Video player element -->
    <canvas id="videoCanvas"></canvas>

    <!-- Include jmuxer library -->
   <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jmuxer@2.0.5/dist/jmuxer.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script>
        // Function to check if the data is H.264 encoded
        function isH264(data) {
            // H.264 NAL unit start code is 0x00 00 01 or 0x00 00 00 01
            if (data.length < 4) {
                return false; // Not enough data
            }
            if (data[0] === 0x00 && data[1] === 0x00 && (data[2] === 0x01 || (data[2] === 0x00 && data[3] === 0x01))) {
                return true; // H.264 start code found
            }
            return false; // Not H.264 encoded
        }

        const socket = io();
        var player;

        socket.on('RemoteVideoByte', bufferdata => {
            if (!player) {
                player = new Player({
                    useWorker: true,
                    workerFile: './Decoder.js',
                    size: { width: 640, height: 480 },
                    webgl: 'auto',
                });
                var canvas = document.getElementById('videoCanvas');
                canvas.appendChild(player.canvas);
            }
  socket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
            var data = new Uint8Array(bufferdata);
            player.decode(data);

            // Check if the decoded data is H.264 encoded
            if (isH264(data)) {
                console.log("Decoded data is H.264 encoded.");
            } else {
                console.log("Decoded data is not H.264 encoded.");
            }
        });

        // Handle any WebSocket errors
        socket.on('error', error => {
            console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

/Jmuxer.js/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Live Video Stream</title>
    <style>
        #player {
            display: block;
            width: 640px;
            height: 480px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>

 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jmuxer@2.0.5/dist/jmuxer.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        const socket = io();
        socket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';

        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('Socket connected');
        });

        socket.on('RemoteVideoByte', bufferdata => {
            jmuxer.feed({
                video: new Uint8Array(bufferdata)
            });
        });

        socket.on('error', error => {
            console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
        });

        var jmuxer = new JMuxer({
            node: 'player',
            mode: 'video',
            flushingTime: 1000,
            fps: 30,
            debug: false
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Can you please help me solve this issue? It would be greatly appreciated.

The Juxer code should work if you fix the part shown below:
Replace: <div id="player"></div>
With the following testing version:
<div id="container_player">
<video id="player" width="500" height="400" controls muted autoplay>
</video>
</div>

It is expected that node: 'player' points to a <video> Element with an ID of "player".
Let me know if this fixes your problem, or else tell what error you get in the console logs.
